# Apply fillna as lambda to entire df with swifter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a line of code to fillna in a pandas dataframe:

```
sessions_combined.fillna('na', inplace = True)
```

This works fine, any null values are replaced with the string 'na' which is what I desire.

However, it's slow. Elsewhere in my code I've been using a lambda function with swifter which processes in parallel using available cores, e.g:

```
import swifter
pages['dimension3'] = pages['dimension3'].swifter.apply(lambda x: my_custom_fun(x))
```

This works fine on a specific column, dimension3.

Is it possible to use swifter on the entire dataframe? Tried:

```
sessions_combined.swifter.apply(lambda x: fillna(x, 'na', inplace = True))
```

> NameError: name 'fillna' is not defined

Comment: not sure but try : `sessions_combined.swifter.apply(lambda x: x.fillna('na', inplace = True))`?

Comment: Yep! That's doing it. Many thanks. I'm not in Python so often. Why is that here? Why x.function and not function(x)

Comment: since fillna is called either upon a dataframe or a series you should call on a series here which is `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a performance boost. But i think it should work like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import swifter
pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(25000000, 4)),columns=list('abcd'))
pdf["pupa"] = None
```

Then:

```
%%timeit
first = pdf.fillna("pupiki")
```

Output: 2.46 s ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

With swifter:

```
%%timeit
second = pdf.swifter.apply(lambda x: x.fillna("pupiki"))
```

Output: 2.41 s ± 39.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: I'm working on a cloud server with several processors so hopefully it speeds up in this environment. Cheers!

Comment: Good luck! I hope you'll share the results. :)

Comment: Does `swifter` support `lambda` function? I believe `dask` does not support it.